# Prevent animation from being applied to <a> inside <li>

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/MabomR

Hover over the 3 non-selected links (Web, Print, Art/3D etc.) and let the cursor stay on the links.

The animation effect itself is ok, but I don't want the text to animate together with the box. This means, while that sonar animation is happening, I want the text to be intact and not be animated with the box.

Is there a way to fix this? Obviously, I can't move the a outside of the `li`. Here's the code for convenience:

```js
$(".nav li").on("mouseover", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("active") == false) {
    $(this).children().first().addClass("sonar");
  }
});

$(".nav li").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).children().first().removeClass("sonar");
});
```

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:link,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:visited,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(74, 74, 74, 1.00);
}
.sonar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 1.00);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: sonarWave 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes sonarWave {
  from {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MySiteLogo</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Web</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Print</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Art / 3D</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your sonar class to animate the `:after` pseudo-element. Just be sure to add a `content:''` for it to kick in:

```
.sonar:after
{
   content:'';
   ...
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjGgqJ

Comment: This is insane, Malk! Tks, awesome! :-D

Comment: What I don't understand is why does this work. Inserting the animation "after" the 'sonar' class is mysterious but it works.